# How to get checked checkbox only into database

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I need to get **only checked** checkbox and **maximum 3 data**, So the uncheck checkbox can't insert into my database

This is the table

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="poTb">
 <tbody>
  <tr class="text-center">
   <th>Pilih</th>
   <td>Kode Obat</td>
    <td>Nama Obat</td>
     <td>Satuan</td>
     <td>Harga Obat</td>
     <td>Jumlah Obat PO</td>
      <td>Total bayar</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($obat as $o)
    <tr>
      <td>
       <input id="check" type="checkbox" name="select[]" value="{{ $o->id }}" id="check">
       </td>
       <td>
       <input type="text" id="kode" class="form-control" name="kode_obat" value="{{ $o->kode_obat }}" readonly>
       </td>
       <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama_obat[]" value="{{ $o->nama_obat }}" readonly>
      </td>
      <td width="15%">
          <div class="form-group">
          <select name="satuanp[]" class="form-control">
          <option value="" hidden>{{ $satuan[0]->nama_satuan }}</option>
          @foreach ($satuan as $s)
     <option value="{{ $s->nama_satuan }}">{{ $s->nama_satuan }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
     </div>
     </td>
      <td>
      <input id="harga-{{ $o->id }}" type="text" class="form-control" name="harga_obat[]" value="{{ $o->harga_obat }}" onkeyup="sum({{ $o->id }})">
      </td>
      <td>
      <input id="jumlah-{{ $o->id }}" type="text" class="form-control" name="jumlah[]" onkeyup="sum({{ $o->id }})" value="{{ old('jumlah') }}">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input id="total-{{ $o->id }}" type="text" class="form-control total-harga" name="total_harga[]" value="{{ old('total_harga') }}" onkeyup="sum({{ $o->id }})">
    </td>
     </tr>
   @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success simpan simp-po" id="addPO"><i class="fas fa-check"> Simpan</i></button>
```

This is Jquery i tried, So if there is no checked checkbox there will be a alert "You must click at least 1", and if the checked checkbox more then 3 there will be alert " Maximum 3 checked", and if there is at least 1 - 3 checked checkbox the data will be insert to the database

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#addPO').on('click', function () {
    var checked = $('#poTb').find(':checked').length;

     if (checked == 0) {
        alert('You must click at least 1 !');
     } else if( checked > 3){
        alert('Maximum 3 checked!');
     }else
           alert('pass');         
     }); 
  });
```

This is the actually looks of the form + table that i made
[image: actually looks like this]

**Update**
Actually I have this field as array in my model

```
 protected $casts = [
        'select'=>'array',
        'jumlah'=>'array',
        'harga_obat'=>'array',
        'total_harga'=>'array',
        'satuan'=>'array',
        'nama_obat'=>'array',
    ];
```

**Example** If i have 2 rows, and i only check 1 checkbox, i need only the checked checkbox data that insert into database not like below
[image: red mark]

Comment: try "$('input[name="select[]"]:checked').length;" this can be help for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this -  `var checked = $('#poTb input:checked').length`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#addPO').on('click', function () {
    var checked = $('#poTb input:checked').length;

     if (checked == 0) {
        alert('You must click at least 1 !');
     } else if( checked > 3){
        alert('Maximum 3 checked!');
     }else
           alert('pass');         
     }); 
  });
```

Comment: Its still the same

Comment: All the data that show in the page is insert into the database even i just check 1 checkbox

Answer (score 0):

try "$('input[name="select[]"]:checked').length;" this can be help for you.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#addPO').on('click', function () {
        var checked = $('input[name="select[]"]:checked').length;
    
         if (checked == 0) {
            alert('You must click at least 1 !');
         } else if( checked > 3){
            alert('Maximum 3 checked!');
         }else
               alert('pass');         
         }
      });
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="poTb">
 <tbody>
  <tr class="text-center">
   <th>Pilih</th>
   <td>Kode Obat</td>
    <td>Nama Obat</td>
     <td>Satuan</td>
     <td>Harga Obat</td>
     <td>Jumlah Obat PO</td>
      <td>Total bayar</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($obat as $o)
    <tr>
      <td>
       <input id="check" type="checkbox" name="select[]" value="{{ $o->id }}" id="check">
       </td>
       <td>
       <input type="text" id="kode" class="form-control" name="kode_obat" value="{{ $o->kode_obat }}" readonly>
       </td>
       <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama_obat[]" value="{{ $o->nama_obat }}" readonly>
      </td>
      <td width="15%">
          <div class="form-group">
          <select name="satuanp[]" class="form-control">
          <option value="" hidden>{{ $satuan[0]->nama_satuan }}</option>
          @foreach ($satuan as $s)
     <option value="{{ $s->nama_satuan }}">{{ $s->nama_satuan }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
     </div>
     </td>
      <td>
      <input id="harga-{{ $o->id }}" type="text" class="form-control" name="harga_obat[]" value="{{ $o->harga_obat }}" onkeyup="sum({{ $o->id }})">
      </td>
      <td>
      <input id="jumlah-{{ $o->id }}" type="text" class="form-control" name="jumlah[]" onkeyup="sum({{ $o->id }})" value="{{ old('jumlah') }}">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input id="total-{{ $o->id }}" type="text" class="form-control total-harga" name="total_harga[]" value="{{ old('total_harga') }}" onkeyup="sum({{ $o->id }})">
    </td>
     </tr>
   @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success simpan simp-po" id="addPO"><i class="fas fa-check"> Simpan</i></button>
```

Comment: Hi it's still the same, i think the problem is because the field jumlah, harga obat, and total harga is array, so it insert all the data that show in there